# PHP - parse webpage using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this webpage I'm trying to parse using SimpleXMLElement to look for a#href "#3" and then get the content of the following span->a which would be "jim":

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>..</head>
    <title>this is the title<title>
    <body>
      <script>...</script>
      <div id="div1">
        something
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div id="src">
            <pre>
                <a name="1" href="#1">1</a>
                <span class="myclass">
                    <a href="somelink123">john</a>
                </span>
                <a name="1" href="#2">2</a>
                <span class="myclass">
                    <a href="somelink2342">dev</a>
                </span>
                <a name="1" href="#3">3</a>
                <span class="myclass">
                    <a href="somelink33452">jim</a>
                </span>
                ....
                ....
            </pre>
        </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm using SimpleXMLElement to get to the children of 'pre' but how would I access elements based on the attributes and then the siblings?

Thanks!

Comment: It would have been useful if you had posted your code as well - shows what your using and how the code could be modified rather than re-write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

This code will look for `a#href "#3"` and find span next to it.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);//Disable libxml errors
$dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");//saved your html as test.html

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$spanVal = $xpath->query("//a[@href='#3']/following-sibling::*[1]");

foreach($spanVal as $span)
{
    echo $span->nodeValue;
}
```

Output:

```
jim
```

Comment: For single matches, you can fetch the string directly as well: `echo $xpath->evaluate(string("//a[@href='#3']/following-sibling::*[1])");`

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath and SimpleXML you could use the following...

```
    <?php
    error_reporting ( E_ALL );
    ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("t1.xml");

    $xml->registerXPathNamespace("d", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
    $elements = $xml->xpath("//d:a[@href='#3']/following-sibling::d:span/d:a");
    foreach ( $elements as $element )   {
        echo $element;
    }
```

I've saved the file as t1.xml (also fixed the end tag of title - so cheated a bit to make it simple).

The main thing here is that there is a default namespace and if you don't include the registerXPathNamespace (using a 'd' as a dummy prefix in this case) then the elements can't be found.  You can see where I've put the `d:` at the beginning of the each element name (i.e. `d:span`)

Answer (score -1):

Try using simple_html_dom_parser. It's pretty easy to use + offers so many options. It's an easy version of DOM. Here's the link -

[simple_html_dom_parser](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library--net-11856)

I hope this would be helpful!

Comment: This is more a comment, either post full answer with code or wait till you have enough rep to comment.